# Read from different directory with respect to home directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to read a file in a directory outside of a key environment directory.
Suppose I have two directories

```
- folder1
  - text1.txt
- folder2
  - text2.txt
```

and I have set:

```
$ export HOME = ".../folder1/"
```

In Python:

```
import os
home = os.getenv("HOME")
```

How will I access `folder2` with respect to `home` directory, like reading `text2.txt`?

Comment: Should it be "../folder1/" and you want to access folder2/text2.txt @Nikko

Comment: Yes @DeveshKumarSingh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to navigate to the file

```
path = os.path.join(home, '..', 'folder2', 'text2.txt')
print(path)
```

The output will be

```
../folder1/../folder2/text2.txt
```

That's because we need to go one level back by `..` to come out of `folder1`, and then go into `folder2/text2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Could you not reference it through a relative path and concatenation?

ie

```py
import os
home = os.getenv("HOME")

folder2 = home + '/../folder2/'
```

Comment: folder1 and folder2 are on the same level

Comment: Yes so the relative path would become ../folder1/../folder2/

So you go into folder 1 then back out then into folder 2 again